# SQLite3 trouble under VC9

Tags: c++, sqlite

I imported sqlite3.c sqlite3.h into my project - and I'm having trouble compiling it.

Errors:

```
1>c:\...\storage_manager.h(7) : error C2079: 'storage_manager::db' uses undefined struct 'sqlite3'
    1>storage_manager.cpp
    1>c:\...\storage_manager.h(7) : error C2079: 'storage_manager::db' uses undefined struct 'sqlite3'
    1>ui_manager.cpp
    1>c:\...\storage_manager.h(7) : error C2079: 'storage_manager::db' uses undefined struct 'sqlite3'
```

Code:

```
#pragma once
#include "sqlite3.h"
class storage_manager
{
    sqlite3 db;
    sqlite3** db_pp;
public:
    void open()
    {
        sqlite3_open("data.db", db_pp);
    }
};
```

Comment: try it without the #pragma once

Comment: Removing the pragma doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed you try to create a stack variable of type *sqlite3* called *db*. That won't work, as sqlite3 is a *handle* and you can only have a pointer variable. You need then to pass the address of that pointer variable to sqlite3_open.

@Neil Butterworth spotted it a bit earlier than me :-)

Comment: Maybe you'll try the forward declarations, they work for me (gcc on Linux)

Comment: Pre-defining the structs in an extern "C" doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to create objects of type sqlite3, only pointers. Remove the line:

```
 sqlite3 db;
```

and everything should be ok.